# Migrating a CA to a new server - CA services won't start

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

We have an Enterprise Root CA running on Server 2012 R2. I built a replacement server running Server 2019 and followed the steps in the below article, I backed up the CA and relevant registry keys, then restored them to the new server. I followed every step exactly.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/migrate-root-ca-to-a-new-server

When trying to start the CA services, I get an error stating **"certificate services won't start 0x80090016 (-2146893802 nte_bad_keyset)"**

[Bad_KeySet_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iwwj.jpg)

In event viewer the error is slightly longer but is pretty much the same...

**active directory certificate services did not start: could not load or verify the current ca certificate. keyset does not exist 0x80090016 (-2146893802 nte_bad_keyset).**

I've been researching for hours but cannot find a solution. I saw a suggestion to create a new certificate and key but that's not an option for us due to our AOVPN relying on the current root CA certificate.

Comment: Has your CA been updated to support signing with an algorithm other than SHA1?

Comment: Yes. Our root ca certificate is SHA256.

Comment: Had you previously switched over from a CSP to Key Storage Provider KSP?